# pycharm django install mysqlclient failed

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

I start a Django project by **Pycharm** and require to use the Mysql as database, there is somthing wrong with installing the mysqlclient package.I have searched the info and downloaded the package from [www.lfd.uci.edu](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient).When I pip install the **.whl** file,it told me not match the platform. But I use the same package to pip install in cmd sucessfully. I wonder there is something different between the venv and local? the detail screenshot as below:
[my venv Python version:](http://m.qpic.cn/psc?/90561551/TmEUgtj9EK6.7V8ajmQrEIkebfytbQilkd.uvCC*MqIUIv8Pr*vdXbPvhq2S7XGI4QO7INpNv13dxdwF2Bn4HYQkw2zEnppZGsrIKXspFNo!/b&bo=4wI1AAAAAAADF.Y!&rf=viewer_4)

`Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`

[I have try some different version mysqlclient](http://m.qpic.cn/psc?/90561551/TmEUgtj9EK6.7V8ajmQrEGeDxzGgWYQN8cXFguIUfo5BpnQxAw*G49xIvaKuMSp9vXJaoIb*BSHl*ECk*uttOr*aBqmc66wqwDR2vt7L14M!/b&bo=oQIpAAAAAAADF7g!&rf=viewer_4)

```
pip  install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

both of above are wrong as below:

```
mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I don`t have the enough reputation to post the image,I just can let them as a tags.I hope someone can help me out.Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

When you already compilred packages on your system it shouldn't cause a problem.

See for more [information](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

If you need an older Version

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

Comment: when I pip install directly, it requires the c++ 14.0

Comment: try an older Version last was 1.4,6, but 2.03 should work also in m3.8.8 and yes you need another versionof c++

Comment: I tried ``pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6``` it still the same error as above. the Pypi I have checked before it just told me "Building mysqlclient on Windows is very hard. But there are some binary wheels you can install easily."

Comment: no i shouldn't be hard, with the VIsual studio build tolls, it was no problem,